# how to make sure my node.js handler finish an api call before it returns a value?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I want to make sure my handler returns "speakoutput" after it receives the result from IBM Watson API. When my code calls IBM API, it will directly jump to "return handlerInput.responseBuilder", because it takes some time for IBM API to analyze the input text.

I tried "await", "promise", but it was not working for my case. "Await" and "promise" could make sure I receive the result from API, but it never prevent my code from jumping to the next line before it finish the API call.

How do I solve this problem?

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    var speakoutput ='';


//IBM API HERE
    var NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/natural-language-understanding/v1.js');
    var nlu = new NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1({
      iam_apikey: 'my_api_key',
      version: '2018-04-05',
      url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-    understanding/api/'
    });


//nlu.analyze takes a lot of time to process
    nlu.analyze(
      {
        html: 'Leonardo DiCaprio won Best Actor in a Leading Role for his performance', // Buffer or String
        features: {
          //concepts: {},
          'keywords': {},
          'relations': {},
          'sentiment': {
            'targets': [
              'in'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error:', err);
        } else {
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
          var temparray = [];
          for (i in response.keywords){
            speakoutput +=response.keywords[i].text;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.keywords[i].text, null, 2));
            temparray.push(response.keywords[i].text);
          }
          console.log(temparray);
        }
      }
    );


//my code will jump to this part before it finishes "nlu.analyze"
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speakoutput)
      .reprompt('What do you want to know? you could search data for atm, course search, fed events,')
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Comment: It's fine that it jumps to `return` --- can you show your code where you call `LaunchRequestHandler.handle(handlerInput)` ? That is probably where your issue is.

Comment: if it returns, then it will return handlerInput.responseBuilder.soeak(speakoutput). speakout = "' if my handler returns before it finishes the api call. i want speakoutput +=response.keywords[i].text;

Comment: I trigger lanchrequesthandler on the cloud(the code i posted is a part of my AWS lambda code).

Comment: Oh sorry, I think what you have said is correct.

Comment: no problem, thank you for your response!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the cb to a promise and return the promise chain as your `handle` function. Whatever calls `handle` must also use `.then()` or `await`

Example of an aync `handle()` can be found at https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-city-guide/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js

```
const GoOutHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'GoOutIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            getWeather((localTime, currentTemp, currentCondition) => {
                const speechOutput = `It is ${localTime
                } and the weather in ${data.city
                } is ${
                    currentTemp} and ${currentCondition}`;
                resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speechOutput).getResponse());
            });
        });
    },
};
```

So for yours:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {



//nlu.analyze takes a lot of time to process
    return (new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ // convert cb to promise

        var speakoutput ='';


    //IBM API HERE
        var NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/natural-language-understanding/v1.js');
        var nlu = new NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1({
          iam_apikey: 'my_api_key',
          version: '2018-04-05',
          url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-    understanding/api/'
        });

        nlu.analyze(
        {
            html: 'Leonardo DiCaprio won Best Actor in a Leading Role for his performance', // Buffer or String
            features: {
                //concepts: {},
                'keywords': {},
                'relations': {},
                'sentiment': {
                    'targets': [
                    'in'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
                var temparray = [];
                for (i in response.keywords){
                    speakoutput +=response.keywords[i].text;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.keywords[i].text, null, 2));
                    temparray.push(response.keywords[i].text);
                }
                console.log(temparray);
                resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakoutput)
            .reprompt('What do you want to know? you could search data for atm, course search, fed events,')
            .getResponse());
            }
        }
        );
    }))
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!!! I tried your code. In my visual studio code debugger, my code first went to.              "return (new Promise(function(resolve,reject){",                   then it went to                      " nlu.analyze(,"                          then it went to                        "})).then(function(temparray){".                        then it returns me errors.   I am using AWS lambda and I am debugging locally.

Comment: I updated my example... an added another one. I can't test it so you might have to do some debugging.